# Realm db encryptionKey

Tags: android, encryption, realm, keychain

For a project of me I need to encrypt the realm DB. Since I wanted it to be as secure as possible I thought that using the Android Keychain was the way to go. But it seems that this isn't available & the same throughout all previous versions of Android.

I got it running by using the example provided in the developer docs and providing a backup method for older API's:
https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html

But even then on some devices there were some problems.

Realm also provides this link:
http://nelenkov.blogspot.dk/2012/05/storing-application-secrets-in-androids.html

It's dated from 2012 and clearly states:

> This article describes how to talk to the system keystore daemon directly and store app-specific secrets in the system credential storage. It will introduce private API's, not available via the Android SDK and some OS services implementation details. Those may change at any time, and are not guaranteed to work. While the techniques described have been tested on a few different devices and OS versions (2.1 to 4.0), there are no guarantees. Use caution if you decide to implement them in a production app.

Are there any recent code examples (using keychain or some sort of device backed security system: I don't want to store the key in the app) that are workable enough on all API versions and not so cumbersome to implement?

**EDIT:** 
MIN SDK 16

Comment: You don't mention what you minSDK is? Also what problems did you run into with keychain?

Comment: Well, i had everything running on my nexus 5 with lollipop. Then I tried on a one+one from a friend of mine and it kept crashing. On another device the encryption key was empty. I know this is quite vague but I didn't keep a record of the exact crash back than.

Comment: The Realm's `README.md` says SDK 19.